# MAC changes back after 30 min or earlier

Tags: mac

I have lubuntu 14.04 system and need to change MAC for internet conncetion to work.

I've done this:

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 hw ether MAC_ADRESS
ifconfig eth0 up
```

But repeatedly after 30 min or less original MAC is restored and I lose Internet connection. Which process can be responsible for this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the OS config for your preferred interface MAC address (hwaddress):

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man5/interfaces.5.html